# How can I remove an "unkeyed" property from an interface?

Tags: typescript

I am importing an interface called WidgetProps from a library to use it as base for other types. Such an interface looks exactly like this:

```
export interface WidgetProps
    extends Pick<
        React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>,
        Exclude<keyof React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, 'onBlur' | 'onFocus'>
    > {
    id: string;
    schema: JSONSchema7;
    uiSchema: UiSchema;
    value: any;
    required: boolean;
    disabled: boolean;
    readonly: boolean;
    autofocus: boolean;
    placeholder: string;
    onChange: (value: any) => void;
    options: NonNullable<UiSchema['ui:options']>;
    formContext: any;
    onBlur: (id: string, value: any) => void;
    onFocus: (id: string, value: any) => void;
    label: string;
    multiple: boolean;
    rawErrors: string[];
    registry: Registry;
    [prop: string]: any; // Allow for other props
}
```

However, when omitting keys using the Omit utility I am not getting any autocompletion nor TS warnings/errors when assigning the new type to a variable.

```
type ValidWidgetProps = Omit<
  WidgetProps,
  | 'autofocus'
  | 'formContext'
  | 'options'
  | 'rawErrors'
  | 'readonly'
  | 'registry'
  | 'schema'
  | 'uiSchema'
>

const a: ValidWidgetProps = {
  // there's no suggestions or errors here
  anyKey: 'some value'
}
```

I noticed that, when removing the last key (which opens the interface for any other property) `[prop: string]: any`, `Omit` works as expected. This is probably normal TS behavior, but I would like to remove that last one without having to clone the whole interface into my code like I did to prove this was causing the error.

Is there a way to remove it? I am using TS `4.5.5`. The interface is from the `react-json-schema-form` lib.